# Implementing Payment Gataway in Laravel based shop

Tags: php, laravel-4, payment

I need a little help with implementing payment getaway in Laravel shop. 
Payment I use is https://gourl.io/ and I can't understand how to take needed information. So I have set the files database table, database connection and all.. Now I'm trying to redirect user to `payment.php` page after order form is submitted. This is my `CartController.php` orderSubmit function

```
public function orderSubmit() {
    $cart = Session::get(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, array());
    if (count($cart) < 1) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

    $validatorRules = array(
        'captcha' => 'required|captcha',
        'shipping_address' => 'required|min:10',
        'shipping_method' => 'required|in:' . implode(',', [Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_NORMAL, Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_EXPRESS])
    );

    Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $validatorRules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/cart/order?_token=' . csrf_token())->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    $shipping = array(
        'quantity' => 1,
        'image' => '/img/noimage.png',
        'description' => '',
        'title' => 'FIX ME', // this should never occur,
        'price' => 100000 // this should never occur
    );
    switch (Input::get('shipping_method')) {
        case Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_NORMAL:
            $shipping['title'] = 'Normal Delivery';
            $shipping['price'] = 0;
            break;

        case Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_EXPRESS:
            $shipping['title'] = sprintf('Express Delivery - $%.2f', Settings::getOption('express_shipping_cost'));
            $shipping['price'] = doubleval(Settings::getOption('express_shipping_cost'));
            break;
    }

    $cart['shipping'] = $shipping;
    $order = new Order();
    $order->user_id = self::$user->user_id;
    $order->data = json_encode($cart);
    $order->address = Input::get('shipping_address');
    $order->pgp_key = Input::get('gpgkey');
    $order->info = Input::get('additional_info');
    $order->save();

    Session::put(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, array());
    return Redirect::to('payment.php')->with('message_success', 'Order created! We will contact you shortly to confirm your order and payment details.');
}
```

and this is payment.php

```
    require_once( "../cryptobox.class.php" );

/**** CONFIGURATION VARIABLES ****/ 

$userID         = "";               // place your registered userID or md5(userID) here (user1, user7, uo43DC, etc).
                                    // you don't need to use userID for unregistered website visitors
                                    // if userID is empty, system will autogenerate userID and save in cookies
$userFormat     = "";           // save userID in cookies (or you can use IPADDRESS, SESSION)
$orderID        = "";
$amountUSD      = 20;           
$period         = "NOEXPIRY";       
$def_language   = "en";             
$public_key     = "mypublickey"; 
$private_key    = "myprivatekey";



/** PAYMENT BOX **/
$options = array(
        "public_key"  => $public_key,   // your public key from gourl.io
        "private_key" => $private_key,  // your private key from gourl.io
        "webdev_key"  => "",        // optional, gourl affiliate key
        "orderID"     => $orderID,      // order id or product name
        "userID"      => $userID,       // unique identifier for every user
        "userFormat"  => $userFormat,   // save userID in COOKIE, IPADDRESS or SESSION
        "amount"      => 0,             // product price in coins OR in USD below
        "amountUSD"   => $amountUSD,    // we use product price in USD
        "period"      => $period,       // payment valid period
        "language"    => $def_language  // text on EN - english, FR - french, etc
);

// Initialise Payment Class
$box = new Cryptobox ($options);

// coin name
$coinName = $box->coin_name(); 

// Successful Cryptocoin Payment received
if ($box->is_paid()) 
{
    if (!$box->is_confirmed()) {
        $message =  "Thank you for payment (payment #".$box->payment_id()."). Awaiting transaction/payment confirmation";
    }                                           
    else 
    { // payment confirmed (6+ confirmations)

        // one time action
        if (!$box->is_processed())
        {
            // One time action after payment has been made/confirmed

            $message = "Thank you for order (order #".$orderID.", payment #".$box->payment_id()."). We will send soon";

            // Set Payment Status to Processed
            $box->set_status_processed();  
        }
        else $message = "Thank you. Your order is in process"; // General message
    }
}
else $message = "This invoice has not been paid yet";

$languages_list = display_language_box($def_language);
```

My question is how to take the correct info in the payment.php? How to take userID, userFormat, orderID and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you use Laravel as the framework it is intended for. In Laravel you define controllers to handle your http-requests. Make a new PaymentController and put the code from payment.php into this controller. Then make a route to that controller-method.

Also put your configuration settings in Laravels config-folder.

And the `require_once( "../cryptobox.class.php" );` can be replaced by a dependency injection in your controllers constructor.

**Now back to your question.**

`$userID` is where you put your registered Laravel user ID. (If you dont have any registered users, leave it blank). Why you should put your user's id in this variable? -It helps to keep track of which users have done which payments. You can later save this information in your database if you want to keep track of payment history.

`$orderID` This is where you put your **internal** order id. Why should you use an internal order id? -Again its to keep track of which purchases of which products have been done by which users. You can store your order-id in your database together with user-id and product-id to get a purchase history log.

`$userFormat` This is how you wish to store your user information, session, cookie, etc. Because when the purchase is executed, the payment gateway needs a way to access this information, and therefor it must be stored in the session or in a cookie.

Comment: Ok, I've made new controller and after order is placed I redirect user to this page but got error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`... I guess I have errors in controller

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException usually appears when you are trying to access the method with the wrong http-verb. For example if you try to call a route defined as a GET with a http-POST

Comment: Now I get `exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:148`. My route is `Route::post('/cart/payment', ['uses' => 'PaymentController@paymentView', 'before' => 'auth|csrf']);` and redirect correctly to `/cart/payment`

Comment: That means you are trying to access a URL that isn't specified in your routes.php file

Answer (score 0):

I would use `$_SESSION['$value']` if you use session for your users!